# Related to int and double

Tags: java

**strong text**
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.print("Enter rectangle length: ");
    double width = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter rectangle width: ");
    double length = keyboard.nextDouble(); 

    double area = length * width;

    System.out.print("Area = " + area);
```

Comment: Why have you put `strong text` in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the "strong text" before  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); will work ok.

```
package adi;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Greeter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter rectangle length: ");

        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter rectangle width: ");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();

        double area = length * width;

        System.out.print("Area = " + area);
        keyboard.close();

    }
}
```